# How neatly does the English-language use of the term(s) "America(n\s)" cross over into Latin American Spanish?

Tags: hispanoamérica, argentina, terminología, estados-unidos, cultura-de-masas

I mean my Question more as a matter of cultural conceptions rather than translation as such.

Coming from the English-speaking (*y originalmente no hablaba español en absoluto*) side of the equation, it has so far been only a few years since I learned, much to my surprise, that in Spanish (for the most part, at least in Latin America and in Europe), North and South America are not in fact two discrete continents, but rather a single one, generally referred to as, simply, *América*.

Quite logically, it follows that anyone from any part of [the] America(s) is an American. The trick with this, however, is the fact that, not only in the USA or even exclusively in English, the term "American" typically tends to connote a person specifically from the country called *the United States of America*.

Both in English and in Spanish, a shortcut around this confusion seems to be the terms Latin America(n\s), hispanoamericanos, and such the like, which cover the vast majority of the non-anglophone parts of *América*.

But **is it at all common for people from América Latina, whether in English or Spanish, to casually refer to themselves simply as "Americans/ *americanos*"** *sans* any qualifiers and generally without expecting the risk of confusion (unless, say, they come from a Spanish-speaking U.S. territory such as Puerto Rico is)?

Many English-speakers that I know would affirm what seems to be obvious, that someone from a continent called "America" (North, South, Central or however you'd want to parse it) is undoubtedly an American. For the most part though, my understanding and experience is that the conception of "American" as referring exclusively to people from the USA is pervasive enough that I have Canadian friends who are quick to eschew the term, emphasising a distinction between themselves and U.S. citizens, while I have Mexican friends who seem bewildered at the discovery of the idea that in English they are not "Americans" as obviously as they've always been precisely that in Spanish.

Further to that, **when *hispanohablantes*** [those among them who are not also English-speakers] **hear U.S. citizens referred to as "Americans" and the nation of the USA called simply "America," is that generally a source of confusion for them**, since, if I understand the use of the terms correctly, in Spanish these terms equate, not to a single country and its inhabitants alone, but to an entire continent and the constituents thereof? Does it tend to create situations in which one wonders: "Hmmm ... *¿Pero de qué parte del vasto continente americano estamos hablando aquí?*"

I recently asked a Mexican and an Argentine this question. They're both fluent in English, though. The Argentine simply said that *latinoamericanos* understand this terminology as "a mistake" made by people from the USA. Is there anything more to it than that? Or is it just as simple as my Argentinian friend puts it?

Comment: From what I have seen, there are *tons* of Spanish-speaking North and South Americans (who are not from the US) who call people from the US "americanos," although offhandedly I think North Americans are more likely to do it due to their proximity to the US (you did not say what your Mexican friend said...), and there are tons of *others* who will tell them they are making a mistake. I must have seen this about a dozen times on YouTube in the comments section.

Comment: That's why you can find posts like [this](https://amp.reddit.com/r/Colombia/comments/k58fx3/ayuda_barrio_bueno_cerca_de_la_embajada_americana/) or [this](https://www.tripadvisor.es/ShowTopic-g312741-i979-k10640625-Hotel_cerca_de_la_embajada_americana_Bs_as-Buenos_Aires_Capital_Federal_District.html). But as to the relative frequency of people who say "american@" and mean the United States, people who say "american@" and mean the continent(s), and people who specifically don't say "american@" to mean the country, I would not know.

Comment: In Argentina, anyone that says "americano" meaning "estadounidense" will be mocked, a lot.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - My Mexican friend kinda just laughed it off. (She's also been a U.S. citizen for like half her life, so I don't know if that's a factor in her perception of the question. Also I did kinda struggle to articulate exactly what I was getting at with this when I talked to her, hence why I'm casting it out here on StackExchange x-D )

Comment: Interesting, @Gaviota - In your experience, would argentinos randomly, in regular conversation, refer to _themselves_ as "americanos."

Comment: @Adinkra Sure. The only meaning the word has is "from America", and for us, America is the continent. Depending of context we may use "latinoamericano" or "sudamericano" or "hispanoamericano" instead. But "americano" will in any case refer to someone from the continent, not from the US.

Answer (score 2):

This topic calls for an entire essay but it suffices to say that, as you've already noticed, *americano/a* is not a generally good translation for (US American) "American" in all situations and, in the particular case of the modern (historically speaking), non-anachronistic designation of United States nationals, it's often a source of conflict. I say conflict, not misunderstanding, because a lot of Spanish-speaking people outside the US, even if they've never met someone from the US and don't speak English at all, know what "American" means in the US, and resent it as an appropriation (of a whole continent, no less!).

I know no Spanish-speaking people (outside the US) who call themselves *americanos* meaning "from the American continent". It's always *latinoamericanos* or, in some fancy circles, *hispanoamericanos* (the root of that has to do with what Brazilians call themselves, if anything). I have no idea if people from other continents, when residing there in their own countries, call themselves by the name of their continent in normal discourse (e.g. do people from Nigeria ever refer to themselves as Africans, outside of specific political contexts?); it sounds weird to me and, I'm sure, to most of my compatriots. We're *argentinos* and, if pressed, *latinoamericanos*—a cultural more than geographical designation.

There's an unspoken consensus that, no matter what we think, *americano* in certain contexts means "US American". *Fútbol americano* is never mistaken for "football played in our continent". The classic German movie *Der amerikanische Freund* is translated as *El amigo americano* and I don't think anyone ever imagined the friend was other than a US native. We know it's not really a mistake by US natives; they're just oblivious to it. Personally I think it's rather stupid to get mad at them, as some people certainly do.

Outside of those contexts, the word does mean "American" in the geographical sense. If I read in an anthropology book that *Los primeros americanos vinieron de Asia a través del estrecho de Bering*, it's obvious that it refers to "the first human inhabitants of the American continent".

Comment: Love the _fútbol americano_ & _Der amerikanische Freund_ examples. I do believe that by "mistake" my Argentinian friend means obliviousness the way you've described it. & I like the point how context would inform which "americanos" we're talking about at a given time.

Comment: In my experience, by the way, a certain Pan-African sentiment does seem to have diffused, in a lot of scenarios, into general culture, so that even outside necessarily political discourse, you would in fact find Kenyans or Nigerians (e.g.) who refer to themselves simply as Africans. But very similarly to your point ref. "latinoamericanos," it is in fact more of a cultural than geographical label: there are also some people from the continent who, for a variety of reasons, find the label to be weird.

Comment: FYI When you say "call themselves by the name of their continent in normal discourse", you obviously haven't encountered Australians.  But then again we're blessed in that our country *is* a continent :)

Comment: @PeterM - You would not be Oceanians, then? :D

Comment: @pablodf76 - Wouldn't you agree that it is fairly common to find people from at least some Spanish-speaking countries in America using the term "american@" to refer to Americans from the United States of America, even as others from the same country reject such a usage? It seems like I see it all the time online, particularly in adjective form. Someone (who is not from the US, Spain, or Equatorial Guinea) will write "los americanos hicieron esto" and then there will be another comment along the lines of "todos somos americanos" or "¿quieres decir los estadounidenses/norteamericanos?"

Comment: In fact just now I read this comment on YouTube «Los americanos le dieron mucha larga a Maduro...ahora se cree el rey de sur América [sic]».

Comment: The problem is that the US doesn't really have a name. "United States" is just a *description* of the political structure, and "America" is its location. And referring to its citizens as "United Statesians" is generally derided. There's "United States citizens", but even that technically does not distinguish citizens of the USA from Mexicans (the official name of Mexico is United Mexican States").

Comment: @Accumulation - "United States of America" *is* its name. The fact that it is also a description of its characteristics is frankly unsurprising. What is unusual is that its name is new enough for people to remember that. But even that is not so unusual. Compare and contrast: South Africa (the country that is in the south of Africa), Central African Republic (the republic in the center of Africa), North Korea (the country in the northern part of Korea), South Korea (the country in the southern part of Korea), Western Sahara (the disputed country in the western part of the Sahara desert)....

Comment: We also have the United Kingdom, or UK (a kingdom, or queendom at the moment, that is a union of other nations), the United Arab Emirates (a union of nations ruled by Emirs who speak Arabic), and Ecuador (the country that is at the equator). However, for people who know a bit of etymology, many more countries are like this, such as the Netherlands (the lands that happen to be low), India (the official name is Bhārat, but the English name means "the land that is near the Indus river"), China (the English name may refer to a dynasty, but the Chinese name 中国, zhongguo, is the "Middle Kingdom").